# What is code 247 returned by Django 1.2.4 development server?

Tags: django

And for that matter, is the set of error codes documented? I get code 247 uploading a large file so I think it's a memory issue but can't find any documentation.

Comment: This isn't a code raised by Django. The dev server will only return HTTP error codes, and there isn't a 247. Can you show the exact output?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to set FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, which will force files larger than that size to be streamed to disk, rather than allowed to continuously consume RAM. I typically set this to 102400, which is 100k.

Hope that helps!