# Django stops without any errors

Tags: python, django, unix

I've set up a django echo server, used for internal uses only. because of this, I run the server with `manage.py runserver &` (yeh, I know, the development mode) with the `&` so it will keep running in the background.
Lately the server always stops working without any notices or error messages.
When I type `jobs` to see the current job, it status is `Exit 247`. Any idea why this happens? I looked online and no help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323159/what-is-code-247-returned-by-django-1-2-4-development-server), code 247 is due to an overconsumtion of memory.

@BetonZM is right, configuring logging is always helpful.

You can also use `>` to redirect the standard output to a file when using `&`.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but for some reason I thought it is not connected. I will dig into it more now.

Answer (score -1):

When using anything in background it is always recommended to log errors.

To log into file just add these lines into **settings**.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'APPNAME.log'),
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

I hope this helps you find your problem!

Comment: didn't work, It stopped again and the log file is empty :(